# Copy and paste sheets using number of a cell

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

i have looked around for the answer to this but i cant find something that really helps answer this question. Its also probably so easy but im new to VBA so i struggle abit. What i need is to do the copy function e.g.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Sheets("Sheet1").Copy Before:=Sheets("Sheet3")
```

This is straight forward but i want it to read the value of cell C22 and depending on this value e.g. 2 i want it to copy this many sheets.

I would really appreciate any help you can give. Thanks :-)

Answer:

```
var1 = Range("C22").Value

For i = 1 To var1
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Sheets("Sheet1").Copy Before:=Sheets(11)
x = x + 1
Next i
```

Comment: You want to get the value in a variable and run a loop the variable amount of times. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this around your code.

```
var1 = Range("C22").Value

For i = 1 to var1
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Copy Before:=Sheets("Sheet3")
Next i
```

Comment: When you refer to Starting sheet do i put something in here because that line of code comes up red?